# jessie-backports-sloppy/ejabberd depends on jessie-backports packages how to solve

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, deb

We have a debian jessie installation and we are trying to install a the package `jessie-backports-sloppy/ejabberd` with

```
# apt-get -t jessie-backports-sloppy install ejabberd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ejabberd : Depends: erlang-asn1 (>= 1:19.2.1+dfsg) but 1:17.3-dfsg-4+deb8u2 is to be installed
            Depends: erlang-base (>= 1:19.2.1+dfsg) but 1:17.3-dfsg-4+deb8u2 is to be installed or
                     erlang-base-hipe (>= 1:19.2.1+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: erlang-crypto (>= 1:19.2.1+dfsg) but 1:17.3-dfsg-4+deb8u2 is to be installed
            Depends: erlang-inets (>= 1:19.2.1+dfsg) but 1:17.3-dfsg-4+deb8u2 is to be installed
            Depends: erlang-mnesia (>= 1:19.2.1+dfsg) but 1:17.3-dfsg-4+deb8u2 is to be installed
            Depends: erlang-odbc (>= 1:19.2.1+dfsg) but 1:17.3-dfsg-4+deb8u2 is to be installed
            Depends: erlang-public-key (>= 1:19.2.1+dfsg) but 1:17.3-dfsg-4+deb8u2 is to be installed
            Depends: erlang-ssl (>= 1:19.2.1+dfsg) but 1:17.3-dfsg-4+deb8u2 is to be installed
            Depends: erlang-syntax-tools (>= 1:19.2.1+dfsg) but 1:17.3-dfsg-4+deb8u2 is to be installed
            Depends: erlang-jiffy (>= 0.14.8) but 0.8.5+dfsg-1 is to be installed
            Depends: erlang-lager (>= 3.4.2) but 2.0.3-1 is to be installed
            Depends: erlang-p1-cache-tab (>= 1.0.10) but 1.0.4-2~bpo8+1 is to be installed
            Depends: erlang-p1-iconv (>= 1.0.5) but 1.0.2-2~bpo8+1 is to be installed
            Depends: erlang-p1-stringprep (>= 1.0.9) but 1.0.6-2~bpo8+1 is to be installed
            Depends: erlang-p1-tls (>= 1.0.15) but 1.0.7-2~bpo8+1 is to be installed
            Depends: erlang-p1-utils (>= 1.0.9) but 1.0.5-3~bpo8+1 is to be installed
            Depends: erlang-p1-xml (>= 1.1.23) but 1.1.15-2~bpo8+1 is to be installed
            Depends: erlang-p1-xmpp (>= 1.1.14) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: erlang-p1-yaml (>= 1.0.10) but 1.0.6-2~bpo8+1 is to be installed
            Depends: erlang-p1-zlib (>= 1.0.2) but 1.0.1-4~bpo8+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

We activated both repos in `/etc/apt/sources.list` with:

```
deb http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports-sloppy main contrib non-free
```

As you can see for an example, one of the packages is available in a working version:

```
# apt show erlang-asn1  -a            
Package: erlang-asn1
Source: erlang
Version: 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2+deb9u1~bpo8+1
Installed-Size: 1,026 kB
Maintainer: Debian Erlang Packagers <pkg-erlang-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Replaces: erlang (<< 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2+deb9u1~bpo8+1), erlang-base (<< 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2+deb9u1~bpo8+1), erlang-base-hipe (<< 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2+deb9u1~bpo8+1), erlang-dev (<< 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2+deb9u1~bpo8+1), erlang-doc (>> 1:19.2.1+dfsg-999), erlang-doc (<< 1:19.2.1+dfsg), erlang-examples (<< 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2+deb9u1~bpo8+1), erlang-manpages (<= 1:11.b.1-2), erlang-mode (<< 1:12.b.1-dfsg-2), erlang-nox (<< 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2+deb9u1~bpo8+1), erlang-src (<< 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2+deb9u1~bpo8+1), erlang-x11 (<< 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2+deb9u1~bpo8+1)
Depends: erlang-base (= 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2+deb9u1~bpo8+1) | erlang-base-hipe (= 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2+deb9u1~bpo8+1), libc6 (>= 2.14)
Suggests: erlang, erlang-manpages, erlang-doc
Homepage: http://www.erlang.org/
Section: interpreters
Priority: optional
Download-Size: 738 kB
APT-Sources: http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
Description: Erlang/OTP modules for ASN.1 support
 The Asn1 application contains modules with compile-time and run-time
 support for ASN.1 in Erlang/OTP.

Package: erlang-asn1
Source: erlang
Version: 1:17.3-dfsg-4+deb8u2
Installed-Size: 1,113 kB
Maintainer: Debian Erlang Packagers <pkg-erlang-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Replaces: erlang (<< 1:17.3-dfsg-4+deb8u2), erlang-base (<< 1:17.3-dfsg-4+deb8u2), erlang-base-hipe (<< 1:17.3-dfsg-4+deb8u2), erlang-dev (<< 1:17.3-dfsg-4+deb8u2), erlang-doc (>> 1:17.3-dfsg-999), erlang-doc (<< 1:17.3-dfsg), erlang-examples (<< 1:17.3-dfsg-4+deb8u2), erlang-manpages (<= 1:11.b.1-2), erlang-mode (<< 1:12.b.1-dfsg-2), erlang-nox (<< 1:17.3-dfsg-4+deb8u2), erlang-src (<< 1:17.3-dfsg-4+deb8u2), erlang-x11 (<< 1:17.3-dfsg-4+deb8u2)
Depends: erlang-base (= 1:17.3-dfsg-4+deb8u2) | erlang-base-hipe (= 1:17.3-dfsg-4+deb8u2), libc6 (>= 2.14)
Suggests: erlang, erlang-manpages, erlang-doc
Homepage: http://www.erlang.org/
Section: interpreters
Priority: optional
Download-Size: 786 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
Description: Erlang/OTP modules for ASN.1 support
 The Asn1 application contains modules with compile-time and run-time
 support for ASN.1 in Erlang/OTP.
```

Does anyone have a solution for that?

Comment: The output of the command `apt policy erlang-asn1` is usually more interesting then `apt-get show` when trying to work with backports.  Since it will report which releases a package is valid for.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to set up [pinning](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) properly, by placing files in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/`.  Maybe something like this?

```
# /etc/apt/preferences.d/ejabberd
Package: ejabberd*
Pin: release a=jessie-backports-sloppy
Pin-Priority:600

# /etc/apt/preferences.d/erlang
Package: erlang*
Pin: release a=jessie-backports
Pin-Priority:600
```